# Excluding categories in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I am creating a bilingual website with woocommerce and WPML.
I have the categories: USA, Canada and Central America, Simple Product, Variable Product and Subscriptions.
I have 30 products that are distributed in those 6 categories.
How do I (for example), by shortcode, code or plugin, in a page, show all USA products that do not have the Subscription category?
Or just show all Canada subscriptions, in a page.
Or only simple products in Central America, in a page.

To clarify the question, I have simple products, variable products and subscriptions in each of these countries or regions.

Or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This plugin will let the user decide what to display:
[Product Filter for WooCommerce](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-product-filter/8514038?ref=NeutrinoTeam)

If this not what you meant I can help you build query to exclude specific product types, etc.